# Java GUI Swing Jlist with three Components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, jcheckbox

I need to create a `Java Swing JList` with three Components.

Each JList row should have one JCheckBox, one ImageIcon and one JLabel. 
The problem is that JLabel could have only two elements. So i need a methode to add a JCheckBox...

Jlist with three components:-

[image]

Comment: `JTable` comes to mind. Start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more ideas

Comment: *"The problem is that JLabel could have only two elements"* - doesn't really make sense

Comment: Thanks

I mean you could create a custom cell renderer and extend from jlabel which could have an icon and a text. But i need a checkbox too. 

So i tried to create a custom JComponent...

Comment: Okay, you're on the right track, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Without any real information, the best I can suggest is start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for how cell renders work.

Based on you basic requirements, you need to start with a container class of some sort and add your components to it, you then need to populate the values of the components each time `getListCellRendererComponent` is called with the data it provides.

You will also need to take care of the selection rendering, since that's normally taken care of by the `DefaultListCellRenderer`

As an example...

[image: Little me introduce you to my little friends]

```
public static class CustomListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Data> {

    private static final Border DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

    private JCheckBox checkBox;
    private JLabel label;

    public CustomListCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(false);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        setBorder(DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER);

        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        label = new JLabel();

        checkBox.setOpaque(false);

        add(checkBox);
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Data> list, Data value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        checkBox.setSelected(value.isSelecetd());
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(value.getImage()));
        label.setText(value.getText());
        Color fg = list.getForeground();
        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            fg = list.getSelectionForeground();
        }
        label.setForeground(fg);
        setOpaque(isSelected);
        Border border = null;
        if (cellHasFocus) {
            if (isSelected) {
                border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
            }
            if (border == null) {
                border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder");
            }
        } else {
            border = DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER;
        }
        setBorder(border);
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

This code works fine for me. I edited a little bit but it works ! I am so happy. Thanks

Comment: You know I look at this and ask my self the question - what reason would anyone have to downvote this?  In what ways does it not answer the OPs question? In what ways could the answer be improved? Since no new answer has been provided, I can only assume that: 1- You don't understand the question; 2- You don't understand the answer 3- You don't have any better idea of how to solve the issue