# checkboxes in jcombobox : never checked

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a question about a JCombobox containing some JCheckBoxes, in java swing.
The problem is that the checkboxes are never checked, because the renderer seems to receive only unselected values; yet the model does contain checked values, I verified it with the debugger. I don't know where the problem is.

here is the code:

a part of the main class constructor:

```
cbb_keywords = new JComboBox();
cbb_keywords.setName("cbb_keywords");
cbb_keywords.addActionListener(this);
cbb_keywords.setMaximumRowCount(5);
cbb_keywords.setRenderer(new CkbKeywordsRenderer(""));
cbbmodel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<CkbKeywordsRenderer>();
cbb_keywords.setModel(cbbmodel);
cbb_keywords.setEditable(true);
```

the code that should trigger the display of some JCheckboxes in the JCombobox:

```
public void setKeywords(Keywords keywords) {
    txf_keywords.setText(keywords.toString());

    DefaultComboBoxModel model = extractComboboxModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
      CkbKeywordsRenderer ckbrenderer =
              new CkbKeywordsRenderer(
                      ((CkbKeywordsRenderer) model.getElementAt(i))
                              .getText());
      if (keywords.contains(ckbrenderer.getText()))
        ckbrenderer.setSelected(true);
      else
        ckbrenderer.setSelected(false);

    }
    cbb_keywords.setModel(model);
}
```

this method could require some explanations: 
* first, "model" is filled with the totality of the keywords stored in a JTable; each row correspond to a book, and each book contains a list of keywords. The filling of "model" begins with collecting all the keywords, and then continues with removing the doubles.
With my debugger, I saw that this field contains 4 keywords : "aventure","jeunesse","maths","philo".
* then, I test each keyword of the model to see if it is in the list of the book's keywords (variable "keywords")(which are : "aventure",and "jeunesse"). 
Thus, in the combobox' list, I should have 4 items, whose 2 are checked : "aventure" and "jeunesse"). If I select in the JTable the other book, the 2 other keywords should be checked in the JCombobox.
* This method was tested and returns a valid model : 4 items whose 2 are "selected"

and now here is the renderer class, which never receives checked values:

```
 public class CkbKeywordsRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer,
        ActionListener {

  static CkbKeywordsRenderer[] elements;

  public CkbKeywordsRenderer(String text) {
    super(text);

  }

  @Override
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
          boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    CkbKeywordsRenderer selectedItem = (CkbKeywordsRenderer) value;

    if (isSelected) {
      setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
      setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    } else {
      setBackground(list.getBackground());
      setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }
    if (selectedItem != null) {

      setText(selectedItem.getText());
      setSelected(selectedItem.isSelected());
    } else if (index == -1 && value == null) setText("abc");
    return this;
  }


  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
    CkbKeywordsRenderer jcheckBox = (CkbKeywordsRenderer) cb.getSelectedItem();
    jcheckBox.setSelected(!jcheckBox.isSelected());
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        cb.showPopup();
      }
    });

  }
```

do you see where is the problem?
thanks

EDIT : no answer... I tried to adapt my program (no JCOmponent in the model) but the renderer is still getting unchecked values:

please have a look at these 2 pictures that summarize very well my problem:

[image: here] you can see that the methode which fills the model does it correctly, 2 of the 4 items are checked.

but [image: here] you can see that the renderer gets a falsely value.

By the way, here is the value's class (it is very simple):

```
public class ItemCombobox {

  public String itemName;
  public boolean checked;

  public ItemCombobox(String itemName, boolean checked) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.checked = checked;
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return itemName;
  }
}
```

and the new code for the renderer is given in the first picture.

thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to get the value from the renderer, but instead from the model.  The renderer should also be rendering the state of the value from model itself. I'd consider using a `JTable` with two columns, but that's me

Comment: Something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442522/java-gui-swing-jlist-with-three-components/36443218#36443218) might help clear up some of the confusion you seem to be having

Comment: Or preferably, [a `JTable` based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851299/inserting-text-alongside-a-checkbox-in-a-jtable-cell/47851633#47851633)

Comment: hello, in your first comment, did you mean replace the line " CkbKeywordsRenderer selectedItem = (CkbKeywordsRenderer) value;"? But the variable "value" contains the selected item. Did you mean using the index value and the getElementAt(i) method (or identical)?

Comment: You shouldn’t be storing components/the renderer in the model, you should only be storing the value of the row. The data and the renderer are separate concepts and should be managed separately

Comment: What do you think of this : the model could be an array of "Datas" instances, each one containing a id number (int) and a boolean to see if it's checked. in the getListCellRendererComponent, the value is of type Datas and the renderer's class inherits from JCheckBox. The JCheckBox returned is selected as with the model object associated with the good id number, in the model. And a click on the JCombobox changes the corresponding "checked" boolean. One last thing : I need to change the JCombobox' model many times, do I need multiples setModel calls or a MutableComboBoxModel?

Comment: or even maybe just an id number in the Data class

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I edited the question, I don't know if you have seen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is based on a "model-view-controller" paradigm. This dictates a separation between the data and the view.

This means the information need to render/display and piece of data is separated from the data itself.  This means that the data can be represented in a number of, independent, ways, depending on what you are trying to use.

This means, the model, should only ever carry the data.  It should never carry any kind of UI element.

Swing also makes use the "delegation" paradigm to allow you to customise how many of the UI components render different elements.  Start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) - This is a really important concept to understand, as it's used almost every where.

You should also have a look at [How to use lists, writing a custom cell renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more specific details.

This is a very basic example which uses your `ItemCombobox` as the basic building block to generate a `JList` which shows the items using a `JCheckBox` as a basic renderer

[image: A Checkbox ListCellRenderer]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultListModel<Item> itemListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("A", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("B", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("C", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("D", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("E", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("F", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("G", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("H", true));

                JList list = new JList(itemListModel);
                list.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxListCellRenderer());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Item {

        public String itemName;
        public boolean checked;

        public Item(String itemName, boolean checked) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return itemName;
        }
    }

    public static class CheckBoxListCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer<Item> {

        private static final Border DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

        public CheckBoxListCellRenderer() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Item> list, Item value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            setSelected(value.isChecked());
            setText(value.getItemName());
            Color fg = list.getForeground();
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                fg = list.getSelectionForeground();
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
            }
            setForeground(fg);
            setOpaque(isSelected);
            Border border = null;
            if (cellHasFocus) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
                }
                if (border == null) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder");
                }
            } else {
                border = DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER;
            }
            setBorder(border);
            return this;
        }

    }

}
```

> But how do I update the item in the list if it changes?

Normally, I'd provide a custom `ListModel` to handle this, but, you can use the `DefaultListModel`'s `setElementAt` to trigger the list to re-render the specified item.

This example simply adds a button, which when triggered, will change the selected state of the selected item (or the first item if one is not selected)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultListModel<Item> itemListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("A", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("B", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("C", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("D", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("E", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("F", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("G", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("H", true));

                JList list = new JList(itemListModel);
                list.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxListCellRenderer());

                JButton change = new JButton("Change");
                change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = 0;
                        }
                        Item item = itemListModel.get(index);
                        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                        // Force an update of the specified element
                        itemListModel.setElementAt(item, index);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.add(change, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Item {

        public String itemName;
        public boolean checked;

        public Item(String itemName, boolean checked) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return itemName;
        }
    }

    public static class CheckBoxListCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer<Item> {

        private static final Border DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

        public CheckBoxListCellRenderer() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Item> list, Item value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            setSelected(value.isChecked());
            setText(value.getItemName());
            Color fg = list.getForeground();
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                fg = list.getSelectionForeground();
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
            }
            setForeground(fg);
            setOpaque(isSelected);
            Border border = null;
            if (cellHasFocus) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
                }
                if (border == null) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder");
                }
            } else {
                border = DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER;
            }
            setBorder(border);
            return this;
        }

    }

}
```

> But how to I allow the user to select/deselect an item from the `JList`?

For me, this is where the concept of using a `JList` for this kind of task starts to fall apart, as a `JList` is generally not meant to be editable.  For me, [I'd prefer a `JTable` based solution instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851299/inserting-text-alongside-a-checkbox-in-a-jtable-cell/47851633#47851633), however...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultListModel<Item> itemListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("A", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("B", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("C", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("D", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("E", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("F", true));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("G", false));
                itemListModel.addElement(new Item("H", true));

                JList list = new JList(itemListModel);
                list.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxListCellRenderer());

                JButton change = new JButton("Change");
                change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = 0;
                        }
                        Item item = itemListModel.get(index);
                        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                        // Force an update of the specified element
                        itemListModel.setElementAt(item, index);
                    }
                });

                list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                        if (index < 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Item item = itemListModel.get(index);
                        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                        // Force an update of the specified element
                        itemListModel.setElementAt(item, index);
                    }                   
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.add(change, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Item {

        public String itemName;
        public boolean checked;

        public Item(String itemName, boolean checked) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return itemName;
        }
    }

    public static class CheckBoxListCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer<Item> {

        private static final Border DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

        public CheckBoxListCellRenderer() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Item> list, Item value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            setSelected(value.isChecked());
            setText(value.getItemName());
            Color fg = list.getForeground();
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                fg = list.getSelectionForeground();
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
            }
            setForeground(fg);
            setOpaque(isSelected);
            Border border = null;
            if (cellHasFocus) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
                }
                if (border == null) {
                    border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder");
                }
            } else {
                border = DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER;
            }
            setBorder(border);
            return this;
        }

    }

}
```

This example simply adds a `MouseListener` to the `JList` and changes the selected state of the item which is clicked.

This has a number of immediate draw backs:

- What if the user just wants to select an item? Now the have to double click the item to reset the state
- There is no keyboard interaction. You could use the key bindings API to add support, but it's not intuitive and now you implementing functionality you'd get for free using a `JTable` based solution anyway
- Generally speaking, it's not intuitive, as `JList` is not meant to be editable, so most users won't have that expectation/mindset and it could cause frustration for the user as their expected results don't meet what your program is now doing.

At this point, I'd say you've exceeded the expected functionality of the `JList`, functionality which would be better managed by using a `JTable`

Comment: thank you, it is very clear now, but the program is still not working as expected...In the first picture of my screen, you can see I use "cbbmodel.setModel(...)", and, I checked, this method fires an event, and change the display the next time I click on the combobox, which is not the case. "getListCellRendererComponent" & "setKeywords" seem both working fine, although the first one receive all values unchecked. I suspect some intermediate code to be executed between the two. Do you confirm? Maybe a simpler example will help me... see you soon!

Comment: So, I've provided you with three runnable examples, you've provided us with none. This is the extent of my ability to help you without some kind of runnable example which demonstrates the actual issue you are having

Comment: yes, you're right ! I will try to make one, one that should not work

Comment: some news : I extracted in a demo program the renderer's handler, and my setKeywords method. I expected it not no work, but it did ! so, the reason was the one I talked to you : therev

Comment: there was some statements between those 2 methods in my program. I ran into a massive debug session, and found a little bug. I fixed this and managed making it work. thank you a lot for all your explanations, your patience. now I know the mvc pattern applied in comboboxes ! happy new year